# How to loop to check either the ID is exist or not in mysql database with PHP after a random function's id is generated?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, random

I have a database called Customers with Unique ID, so each time insert from php to database I need to generate a new ID for the new customer from a random function but I need to check the id that generated is exists in database or not.

This is the php random function:

```
function randomDigits($length){
    $digits = "";
    $numbers = range(0,9);
    shuffle($numbers);
    for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++)
       $digits .= $numbers[$i];
    return $digits;
}
```

I tried to pass random length like this:

```
    $cusid = randomDigits(10);
    $generate_customer_id = "";

    $query_customer_id = dbQuery("SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE customer_id = '$cusid'");
    $count_customer_id = $query_customer_id->rowCount();

    if($count_customer_id == 1)
    {

        $generate_customer_id = randomDigits(10);

    }
    else
    {
        $generate_customer_id = $cusid;
    }
    $query = dbQuery("INSERT INTO customers(`customer_id`,`username`,`password`,`email`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`dob`,`id_card`,`family_book_id`,`address`,`district`,`province`,`phone`,`mobile`,`father_name`,`mother_name`,`bank_account_no`,`bank_account_name`) VALUES('$generate_customer_id','$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dob','$idcard','$familybook','$address','$district','$province','$homephone','$mobilephone','$fathername','$mothername','$bankno','$bankname')");

    if($query == true)
    {
        $insert_referrer = dbQuery("INSERT INTO referrers (`parent_id`, `customer_id`, `category_id`, `created`,`modified`) VALUES(NULL, '$generate_customer_id', 2, NOW(), NOW())");
        if($insert_referrer == true)
        {
            echo "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "There is an error please check your information and try again referrers!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There is an error please check your information and try again customers!";
    }
```

But data return from my AJAX function, if return error I need to click the save customer button many times then i will return success and then data successful saved to database.

But I want user to click only one time then data will insert.

How to implement this please help!

EDiT:
This is AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/admin/sales/ajaxAddSalesParent.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(responseMessage){
            if(responseMessage == "OK")
            {
                swal({
                      title: "Success",
                      text: "Your requested has been completed!",
                      type: "success",
                      showCancelButton: false,
                      confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
                      closeOnConfirm: false
                    },
                    function(isConfirm) {
                      if (isConfirm) {
                        window.location.href = "sales_members.php";
                      } 
                });

            }
            else
            {
                $.alert({
                    title: '<h3 style="color: red;">Error!</h3>',
                    content: responseMessage,
                    confirm: function(){

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX function?

Comment: I updated the Ajax function, so please help me how to use the random function number to check the customer_id from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run following select on your database:

```
select floor(1000000000 + rand() * 8999999999) as rndID, 
(select customer_id from customers where customer_id=rndID) as uniq;
```

then you will receive a 10 digit random number and hopefully uniq being NULL.

so actually just perform this query in a while loop until field `uniq` is NULL and there you have your unique random number in the `rndID` field.

I don't have your environment for testing, but i reckon following solution should work:

```
// get random customer id
$generate_customer_id = 0;
do {
    if ($result = dbQuery("select floor(1000000000 + rand() * 8999999999) as rndID, (select customer_id from customers where customer_id=rndID) as uniq")) {
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['uniq']!=$row['rndID'])
                $generate_customer_id = $row['rndID']; 
        }
    }
} while($generate_customer_id == 0);

$query = dbQuery("INSERT INTO customers(`customer_id`,`username`,`password`,`email`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`dob`,`id_card`,`family_book_id`,`address`,`district`,`province`,`phone`,`mobile`,`father_name`,`mother_name`,`bank_account_no`,`bank_account_name`) VALUES('$generate_customer_id','$username','$password','$email','$firstname','$lastname','$dob','$idcard','$familybook','$address','$district','$province','$homephone','$mobilephone','$fathername','$mothername','$bankno','$bankname')");

if($query == true)
{
    $insert_referrer = dbQuery("INSERT INTO referrers (`parent_id`, `customer_id`, `category_id`, `created`,`modified`) VALUES(NULL, '$generate_customer_id', 2, NOW(), NOW())");
    echo ($insert_referrer) ? "OK" : "There is an error please check your information and try again referrers!";
}
else
{
    echo "There is an error please check your information and try again customers!";
}
```

Comment: So that mean I can get a new ID for new customer without the random function right? but 1000000000 + rand() * 8999999999 return more than 10 digits so please! I need unique ID  because customers could be a thousand, a million of customer. so I want the ID for each customer. But please how to implement my current code please?

Comment: no, actually the select should return only 10 digits, no more and no less. the first value is the min value '1000000000' which is 10 digits and the second value is the max value '8999999999' which is also 10 digits. so if rand() returns 0 then you will get min value and if rand() returns 1 then you will get min+max = 9999999999 also 10 digits. rand() will return any number between 0 and 1 so you will get all flavors in-between.

Comment: but still you have to check that second field is NULL, only then you are sure that the number returned is unique in your table

Comment: So can you show me an example of looping your query the return the unique ID?

Comment: test the sample i just provided now

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tested your suggested code on a separate file I get the ID of that query but my problem still there it might be cause by my insert query or something else so I will take a look more about this. Anyway thanks for the sample code